# where should I put my html file so I can read it via Wordpress and/or Apache

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, wordpress

where should I put my html file so I can read it via Wordpress and/or Apache that I've installed ? where is the root diractory of my site (192.168.1.xxx) ?

thanks

Comment: /var/www/ is where you extract the WordPress compressed file. And since Apache is your local server, directory would be 127.0.0.1 or just type localhost in the browser.

Comment: Sorry I may have give more details. Actually I can access my home page in Wordpress when I connect to my local address of raspberry (which is something like 192.168.1.xxx, but localhost would also do). I can see Wordpress blog, etc. But I have an old html file that I'd like to view when in my browser. That is I want to create a link pointing to that file and put that file where I can access it. I tried several location under /var/www but none is working. In short, please tell me 1/ Where to put my html file 2/ What to do (link creation) in Wordpress to access that html file

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the HTML file to let's say, old.HTML. you are able to access that by going to 192.168.1.xxx/old.HTML. if you wish you may name it index.HTML and keep it in a folder in the /var/www/ directory. So the location of your HTML document would be /var/www/[newfolder]/index.HTML, where [new_folder] may be anything you wish. Then you would go to 192.168.1.xxx/[new_folder]/ and you will see your webpage

Comment: Your welcome. Would you mind selecting me as best answer? Thank you.